# How to get genre of the album for spotify app

Tags: javascript, spotify, last.fm, musicbrainz

I would like to retrieve the genre of the track/ album being currently played in Spotify.

I've looked at Last.FM for getting the genre from the album or from the track but it seems there is no option.

Please can someone help me to find the genre via a web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend using [Echo Nest API](http://developer.echonest.com/) as Last.fm only uses user inputted tags, which aren't always helpful.

Comment: @JIeagle can you please give me example of webservice

Comment: Do you please give me some other api links ,which are famous & do not require api authentication or i can use directly (means open source)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get this problem in the MusicStore Project? If you do, open `Album.cs`, find this :

```
public Genre Genre { get; set; }
public Artist Artist { get; set; }
```

and add a virtual attribute like:

```
public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
```